# Get full actual html page source including the frameset

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vbscript, qtp

For our functional test automation we use QTP with the Webtest Plugin. I have control over the DOM (but not in an easy manner) and can use VBScript and partially Javascript to find a solution.

Whenever we encounter an error during a test I'd like to capture the full HTML page source at that moment. Later, when we are inspecting the error from our reports, we can see what happened and how the DOM looked like at that moment.

Therefore I look for a posibility to capture this source. Normally I did it with

```
htmlSource = browser("micClass:=Browser").page("micClass:=Page").Object.documentElement.outerHTML
```

or

```
htmlSource = browser("micClass:=Browser").page("micClass:=Page").Object.getElementsByTagName("html")(0).innerHTML
```

Unfortunately this will only capture the full content of the  tag the frameset, and the frames, but not the actual content that is located in the frames. (classic frames here, not IFrames)

Now I'd like a way to capture the full DOM source at real time including the content in the framesets. And I'd like them in the right order and place, just like the source appears in the HTML view of the IE Developer Tool.

Does anyone have an idea how I could manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really **need** to have the frames' source inline in the page's HTML the only way I know of achieving this is build the HTML recursively for each element. This may be a lot of work since for every element you'll have to remove the `innerHTML` from the `outerHTML` before going to the child elements (and insert them correctly).

If you can live with the frames' HTML being outside you can use `Page.ChildObjects()` with a description `micclass=Frame` and then use the same mechanism you used for the page (`frames(i).Object.documentElement.outerHTML`).

Note that you'll get all the frames under the page so there's no need to get the child objects of the `Frame` test objects even if the frames are nested in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you Motti, I was afraid it would be something like that. Building it recursively would take too much performance, so maybe I try the getframes trick. It's going to be ugly but if that is my only chance, then ugly it is.